# Inconvertible types. Достаточно ли это гибкая библиотека,чтобы подстроить под мою ситуацию

Tags: java, android

Библиотека ASNE. Примеры работы с библиотекой и используемый мною код из статьи https://habrahabr.ru/post/237095/

В коде я указал ошибки в комментариях. В примере программы вместо диалог фрагмент используется фрагмент, мне требуется подстроить всё это дело в диалог фрагмент. Что для этого нужно сделать? Как избавиться от этих ошибок?

```
public class GameOverFragment extends DialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener,  View.OnClickListener,  SocialNetworkManager.OnInitializationCompleteListener, OnLoginCompleteListener {

        private View form = null;
        public static SocialNetworkManager mSocialNetworkManager;

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View form = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                    .inflate(R.layout.gameoverfragment, null);
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(form);

            Button vk_share = (Button)form.findViewById(R.id.vk_button);
            vk_share.setOnClickListener(this);

            String VK_KEY = getActivity().getString(R.string.vk_app_id);

            String[] vkScope = new String[] {
                    VKScope.FRIENDS,
                    VKScope.WALL,
                    VKScope.PHOTOS,
                    VKScope.NOHTTPS,
                    VKScope.STATUS,
            };

            mSocialNetworkManager = (SocialNetworkManager) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(SOCIAL_NETWORK_TAG); //Ошибка: Inconvertible types. Cannot cast android.app.Fragment to com.github.gorbin.asne.core.SocialNetworkManager

            if (mSocialNetworkManager == null) {
                mSocialNetworkManager = new SocialNetworkManager();

    VkSocialNetwork vkNetwork = new VkSocialNetwork(this, VK_KEY, vkScope);// Здесь вместо this требует android.support.v4.app.Fragment
                mSocialNetworkManager.addSocialNetwork(vkNetwork);

            return dialog;
        }


        public void onClick( View v){
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.vk_button: {


                }break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, что я должен немного править код библиотеки. В VkSocialNetwork в библиотеке на вход вместо Fragment написать DialogFragment. Подключенную библиотеку править не получается, наверно придется код библиотеки вручную добавить в проект.

Comment: Измените импорт в файле. Вместо `import android.app.DialogFragment` укажите 
`import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;` и должно перестать ругаться на `this`.

Comment: Но почему?? он перестал ругаться на обе ошибки ,которые в закомментированы в коде.

Comment: Потому что это разные классы, хоть и называются одинаково. Один из SDK второй из google support library. Ваша библиотека очевидно работает только со вторым.

Comment: Да я понял, что android.support.v4.app новая библиотека обновляемая после api 11. Спасибо, пойду смотреть не вылезло ли других ошибок